# vimrc configuration

Tags: vim

I'm sorry if my title seems vague. I wasn't sure how to make a succinct title.

I have 2 questions:

1) For tab movement in vim, when I map ctrl+pgup to ctrl+p and ctrl+pgdown to ctrl+n, it works fine moving between tabs but each time I move from a tab to different tabs and come back to said tab, the cursor moves one space to the right (it goes to the next line if it meets the end of the line)
The mapping looks like this in my .vimrc file

```
map ^N ^[[6;5~ 
map ^P ^[[5;5~
```

2) I want to check if the colorscheme is a certain one and if so then do sth. eg I want to do this:

```
if &colorscheme == desert256
    highlight String ctermfg=217 ctermbg=235
endif
```

Comment: You might want to ask this on superuser.com

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is on https://superuser.com/questions/103293/vimrc-configuration